# Jquery wrappAll nextUntil

Tags: jquery, wrapall

How to wrap all li under the gfield_html in a div.

Presently we are using this :

```
$('.gfield_html').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).nextUntil('.gfield_html').wrapAll('<div class="box"></div>');
});
```

But the second gsection is wrapped into the div, and it's a title so we don't want this to be wrapp.

Here is the structure

```
<li class="gsection">test</li>
<li class="gfield_html">test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>

<li class="gsection">test2</li>
<li class="gfield_html">test2</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test2</li>
```

Comment: So you only want to wrap the first one?

Comment: we want to wrap all li's under gfield_html in independant div

Comment: There are no `li` tags underneath `gfield_html`?

Comment: under the li with the gfield_html class we have other li

Comment: the jquery code above is working but he wrapp the li with the class gsection in the div. We don't want that li to be wrapped

Comment: then do `nextUntil('.gsection')` instead - Also that would create invalid HTML.. LI Permitted Parents - `Permitted parent elements An <ul>, <ol> or <menu> element. Though not a non-conforming usage, the obsolete <dir> may also be a parent.`   UL Permitted Content- `Permitted content zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements.`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wrap only elements between `gfield_html` and `gsection` then you can do this way

```
$('li.gfield_html').each(function(){
    var $set = $();
    var nxt = this.nextSibling;
    while(nxt) {
        if(!$(nxt).is('li.gsection')) {
            $set.push(nxt);
            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
        } else break;
    } 
   console.log($set.wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />'));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5jR/)**

**[PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/fv26VXC3)**

Comment: that don't seem to wrapp the second block

Comment: @PatriceB..If you generated source of the OutPut HTML,you should see all the elements wrapped as you need. See my updated answer.isn't this way you need?